# If $X$ is a topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$, then is there a homeomorphism $h:X\to X$ such that $h[U]\subseteq V$?

What about such that $h[U]\subseteq V$ *and* $h[V]\subseteq U$?

Comment: What if $X$ is finite and $\operatorname{card}(U) > \operatorname{card}(V)$? Then clearly, any map $h : X\to X$ such that $h(U)\subseteq V$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

This is false even for the additive group of reals, for $V=(-1,1)$ and $U=\Bbb R\setminus [-1,1]$, because $\overline{V}$ is compact whereas $\overline{U}$ is not.